# SQlite 3 PDO statements failing in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo, database-connection

Why does the following statement fail in php (I have an established PDO connection to sqlite database named config.db).

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO config (S_BASE_DIR) VALUES (':col0')");
$stmt->bindParam(':col0',$colValue);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

The exact error is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 bind or column index out of range'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When binding to a column, you do not need to quote the column:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare( "INSERT INTO config (S_BASE_DIR) VALUES ( :col0 )" );
$stmt->bindParam(':col0', $colValue);
```

With quotes around the `:col0` it is just a string, and not a binding parameter.